# [FireDac][Phys][MySQL]-1101. Unsupported MySQL version [0]. Supported are client and server from v 3.20 to v6.2

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

Does anyone know how to solve this Error on RAD Studio XE6 Delphi

If you take the sample app supplied by Embarcadero 
FireDAC\Samples\Comp Layer\TFDConnection\DLL_Sharing and change the FDConnection to use a MySQL server instead, you get this error.
[FireDac][Phys][MySQL]-1101. Unsupported MySQL version [0]. Supported are client and server from v 3.20 to v6.2.

The connection in the exe works, using the MySQL server, but the sharing in the DLL does not.
Even though the steps in the FireDAC DLL_Sharing are followed..

Comment: Have you followed the way described in [`this paragraph`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Connect_to_MySQL_Server_(FireDAC)#Windows_Client_Software) ? There's a note saying *"Ideally, the version (of the client library for connecting to MySQL server) should be equal to the server version."*. Do you meet that suggestion ?

Comment: The error code mentioned in "this paragraph" is not the same I am getting a -1101 not a -314

Comment: I know, I mean if you tried to use a client library matching in version with the server that you're connecting to.

Comment: ok, soz. Yes i have even added a TFDPhysMySQLLink and used the libmysql.dll from the bin folder of the mysql server.

Comment: Even using the MySQLDriverLink does not solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the file FireDAC.Phys.MySQLWrapper.pas (from source\data\firedac directory) to your project directory, edit the file, and look for the following three lines:

if (FVersion < mvMySQL032000) or (FVersion >= mvMySQL060200) then
    FDException(OwningObj, [S_FD_LPhys, S_FD_MySQLId], er_FD_MySQLBadVersion,
      [FVersion]);

Remove them (or place them in comments), and rebuild your project. Make sure that it uses the FireDAC.Phys.MySQLWrapper from your project directory (you may have to close and re-open the project to ensure it uses your local unit).

That way, you still won't be able to connect at design-time, but at least it will work at runtime.

Groetjes, Bob Swart

Answer (score 0):

Use the "original" mysql libmysql.dll and its work fine ;)
the mariadb's libmysql.dll causes this error